# Understand FileStream in File.Create and File.Write

Tags: c#, filestream

I cannot understand why I need to dispose the **File.Create** or wrap the creation within a using station before accessing the file and write to it. Why do I need to dispose that instances of **Stream** class that **File.Create** initialized, and have to create another **Stream** instance  to write to it? Are they on a different thread, why?

Why can't creation, text-writing, and deletion share the same **Stream**? Perhaps I just do not understand **Stream**.

For example:

```
File.Create(...);
File.ReadLine(...); <-- The process cannot access the file ... because it is being used by another process

using (File.Create(...)) {};
File.ReadLine(...); <-- OK
```

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding, but you can share the same stream instance among write, read, etc. You also don't need to wrap stream in USING - you can dispose manually after use. Dispose is to prevent memory issues and isn't itself even 100% necessary in that the program will still compile and run if you do not dispose. Perhaps you could share some specific code to outline your questions.

Comment: `File.ReadLine(...)` is wrong no such thing it is `File.ReadLines(...)`, You could try something like `var fs = File.Create(...);
            fs.Dispose();
            File.ReadLines(...);`

Comment: Yes. And I want to know why fs.Dispose() - that is the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the *Remarks* section on the [`File.Create`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d62kzs03(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN (emphasis mine):

> The FileStream object created by this method has a default FileShare
>   value of None; no other process **or code** can access the created file
>   until the original file handle is closed.